# Consultar dos o mas columnas de dos o mas tablas en una sola sentencia

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos tablas `Usuarios` y `Logs`.

En la tabla `Logs` tengo `ID, fecha, hora, usuario, estado, estaciòn`.
En la tabla `Usuarios` tengo `ID, Empleado, Nombre, Apellido, permisos, ID_Campaña, horario`.

Necesito crear una sentencia que consulte de la tabla Logs los campos de `fecha, hora , usuario, estado` y que de la tabla Usuarios me consulte el `nombre, apellido`.

La tabla Logs contiene cerca de 1500 a 2000 registros por día, y a su vez múltiples registros de un solo usuario.

Quería usar un `Inner join`, pero no obtengo el resultado que quiero.

Aquí me isentencia:

```
SELECT `Date` , `Time` , `UserName` as  'Employee' , `Status` 
  FROM `logs` 
  Inner  JOIN (SELECT `FName` , `LName` , `Campaign_ID`,`Employee`  FROM `users`) users 
    ON `UserName` = `Employee` 
      WHERE `logs`.`Date` = '1/11/2018' 
      And `logs`.`Time` > '07:00:00' And `logs`.`Time` < '08:00:00' 
      And `logs`.`Status` Between 'Clocked In' 
      AND 'Clocked Out' order by `logs`.`UserName`
```

Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta asi:

```
SELECT u.Nombre , u.Apellido, l.fecha, l.hora, l.usuario, l.estado from Usuarios u, Logs l where u.id = l.empleado and l.date between 'fecha_1' and 'fecha_2' and l.estado in ('Clocked In', 'Clocked Out')
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda Jialzate. ha funcionado perfecto! No sabia que se pudiese hacer un SELECT FROM con dos tablas. Había pasado  todo el día viernes partiéndome la cabeza, buscando información sobre Joins. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Es con mucho gusto, no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos formas de hacerlo:

Entiendo que el campo usuario de la tabla log es FK de la tabla usuario

```
SELECT u.nombre, u.apellido, l.fecha, l.hora, l.usuario, l.estado FROM log l, usaurio u WHERE l.usuario=u.id;
```

La otra es con Inner join:

```
SELECT u.nombre, u.apellido, l.fecha, l.hora, l.usuario, l.estado FROM log l INNER JOIN usuario u ON u.id=l.usuario;
```

Comment: Me quedaría con la segunda opción, pero todos los `as`, sobran. Bastaría con `SELECT u.nombre, u.apellido ...` la columna tomará el nombre que ya tiene, no entiendo por qué usas `as`

Comment: Lo suelo poner por que cuando desarrollo aplicaciones y quiero acceder al valor de un campo por su nombre se me es más fácil y desde mi punto de vista me parece una buena práctica.

Comment: En este caso no es una buena práctica. `AS` es un **alias**, y debe usarse cuando el campo se llama de un modo y tú quieres llamarlo de otro modo. Si el campo se llama `nombre` y tú usas `as nombre` estás incurriendo en una redundancia: **le estás asignando un alias igual a su nombre**. Tienes que usar `AS` si por ejemplo quieres acceder al campo por otro nombre: `SELECT u.nombre as nombre_usuario ...`. En ese caso tú quieres acceder a ese campo como `nombre_usuario`, ahí sí tendría sentido usar un alias.

Comment: Para acceder al campo desde una aplicación por el nombre tendrías que hacerlo con "u.nombre" uso le AS solo por comodidad y como comente es mi punto de vista, en esto caso no hay una regla que diga que se haga de una u otra manera, depende del que haga el script. He hecho Querys hasta con 5 tablas  y usar el AS se me ha vuelto costumbre.

Comment: Creo que estás confundido en ese punto. Cuando tú usas  `u.nombre`, esa columna no te vendrá siendo llamada `u.nombre`, lo que tú le dices ahí es que te traiga la columna llamada `nombre` de la tabla `u`. Te lo digo por experiencia, yo uso mis consultas así, haciendo `JOIN` y puedo acceder a esa columna como `nombre`. De hecho, si observas los resultados en el manejador verás que la columna se llamará `nombre` y no `u.nombre`.

Comment: [Aquí tienes un ejemplo de lo que digo](http://rextester.com/TDLN10060). Observa el `SELECT` al final de todo: `SELECT  a.producto_id, a.fecha FROM  ...` y observa que en los resultados las columnas no se llaman `a.producto_id` ni `a.fecha`,  sino que se llaman `producto_id` y `fecha`. Aunque hayas adquirido esa práctica, te hago saber que al hacer eso estás escribiendo **código redundante**. `AS` es para otorgar un alias a la columna. **Es una mala práctica** y enseñar a otros a escribir código redundante también es una mala práctica.

Comment: Lo acabo de comprobar y tienes razón, aunque dos columnas de distintas tablas tengan el mismo nombre las columnas se llaman igual. Agradezco tu observación modificaré mi respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: De nada. En el caso de que en el `SELECT` haya dos columnas que se llamen igual entonces sí deberías usar `AS` **con una de ellas**, para diferenciarla de la otra, ya que en ese caso no podrías acceder por programación a las dos columnas indistintamente. Pero si hay una sola con ese nombre el uso de `AS`  sería redundante. Saludos.